# Writing/reading in an android app and the termination

Tags: java, android

at the moment I'm trying to do some of the "beginning android games" book tasks.

So, this is my "Settings" class code and it suppose to read and write some information from my app.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import com.book.framework.FileIO;

public class Settings {

public static boolean soundEnabled = true;
public static int Monsters = 0;
public static int Ores = 0;
public static int maxLevel = 0;

public static void load(FileIO files) {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                files.readFile("vars.txt")));
        soundEnabled = Boolean.parseBoolean(in.readLine());
        Ores = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        Monsters = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        maxLevel = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
    } catch (IOException e) {

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

    } finally {
        try {
            if (in != null)
                in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}

public static void save(FileIO files) {
    BufferedWriter out = null;
    try {
        out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                files.writeFile("vars.txt")));
        out.write(Boolean.toString(soundEnabled));
        out.write(Integer.toString(Ores));
        out.write(Integer.toString(Monsters));
        out.write(Integer.toString(maxLevel));
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally {
        try {
            if (out != null)
                out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}

public static void addLevel(int level) {
    if(level > maxLevel)
        maxLevel = level;
}
}
```

I add the value to the Monsters,Ores and maxLevel values in some other classes of my app and I use the "save" method every time one of the variables is updated. Reading happens just after I start my app.
Now to the problem. When I exit the app with back>back>back the values are saved and everything works fine. However, when I press(and hold) the "Home" button and terminate the app this way the information(Monsters, Ores and maxLevel) doesn't save, well actually it just goes to default(0,0,0). So, the question is - how can I keep my variables untouched in such situations? I feel like I need to change my Settings class a bit, but not quite sure where and how.

P.S. the last method is irrelevant

Thank you for your responses

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: I thought I was saving them to the "vars.txt" file by calling the "save" method, is that not correct? For example this is a part of my main class
'if (inBounds(event, 0, 240, 800, 240)){
lvl++;
Settings.addLevel(lvl);
Settings.save(game.getFileIO());
}'
The lvl is just a private variable of the executive class and it keeps the value of the current lvl(of the game). Whenever the current mission/map is finished the lvl is being compared with the maxLevel and if the new value is higher than the maxLevel the maxLevel will get that value and then will be saved.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the scroll bar there so missed the rest of your code.

Comment: One obvious issue is that you have catch blocks which will conceal your exceptions, so if something goes wrong you will never find out what!   At least for now, each of those should have e.printStackTrace() in it.

Comment: thanks a lot, now I at least know what are the problems